# android mapView errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mapview

I do the same thing from an [example](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android), but Eclipse returns errors. Code is the following:

```
package hello.google.map;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
{    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the errors:

*

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type    HelloGoogleMapsActivity.java    /HelloGoogleMaps/src/hello/google/map   line 7  Java Problem
MapActivity cannot be resolved to a type    HelloGoogleMapsActivity.java    /HelloGoogleMaps/src/hello/google/map   line 13 Java Problem
The import com.google cannot be resolved    HelloGoogleMapsActivity.java    /HelloGoogleMaps/src/hello/google/map   line 3  Java Problem
The import com.google cannot be resolved    HelloGoogleMapsActivity.java    /HelloGoogleMaps/src/hello/google/map   line 4  Java Problem
The method isRouteDisplayed() of type MapsActivity must override a superclass method    HelloGoogleMapsActivity.java    /HelloGoogleMaps/src/hello/google/map   line 18 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MapsActivity must override a superclass method  HelloGoogleMapsActivity.java    /HelloGoogleMaps/src/hello/google/map   line 11 Java Problem
The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type MapsActivity   HelloGoogleMapsActivity.java    /HelloGoogleMaps/src/hello/google/map   line 14 Java Problem
The public type MapsActivity must be defined in its own file    HelloGoogleMapsActivity.java    /HelloGoogleMaps/src/hello/google/map   line 7  Java Problem*
```

Why? What I do wrong?

Comment: Have you select proper Google API??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it there could be two things you missed.
Either you forgot to add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Or, you are trying to run it on an emulator with a stock Android API instead of the special Google API version. You need this  Google API version to use functions such as the map.

If you don't have it, no worries, you can download it in the SDK Manager. Afterwards simply create a new AVD and set the target to the Google API version of your targetted API level.

Comment: Must likely this or the ApiKey maybe.

Comment: Nah not the API key. It works without the key, it just shows a blank map when you do. In his case it crashes before showing the map, simply because it has no idea what a MapActivity is, among others.

Comment: I missed nothing. Manifest and view file are ok. I also got API key too. Problem only with class

Comment: But are you using the Google API as your build target though. That's most likely the problem here.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I need to create a new AVD targeting the APIs

Comment: @Sandervan'tVeer True, forgot that. :-) +1 nice comment

Answer (score 0):

use this after your setContentview in on create

```
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

and put

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" >
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


</app...>
```

Comment: rename your Activity file with MapsActivity.java also in manifest file clean your project and run again it is problem from HelloGoogleMapsActivity.java use same name in manifest and src folder

Answer (score 0):

Your error log says the file name is `HelloGoogleMapsActivity.java` but your class name is `MapsActivity`. Are you sure you are doing the right thing? Try changing the class name to `HelloGoogleMapsActivity` or file name to `MapsActivity`. In both case update your manifest.

According to your link the main Activity is `MapsActivity` and is defined in the file `MapsActivity.java`. So you can cange the file name to `MapsActivity.java` to match the example.